# Get string using RegEx in Java

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

No matter how much I try to learn RegEx and implement them, I fail.

Below : The first value is the input string, values after colon are the terms I require from the string. The term will always be -> either **Input! (A-Z) (number)**  or **Calc! (A-Z) (number)**

e.g.Input!A34 or Calc!D93.

Input : Need to replace with some constant/val

ADD(Input!A34 + Calc!D93) : Input!A34, Calc!D93

Input!D343 = 1000 : Input!D343

Calc!D71=IF(HasValue(Input!D4), "FormIs(PartofReturn)", IFERROR(1/0)): Calc!D71,Input!D4

What pattern should I use for this ?

My try :

```
Pattern findMyPattern = Pattern.compile("(?:Input|" + "Calc!"
                + ")![a-zA-Z]\\d+");
        Matcher foundAMatch = findMyPattern.matcher(input);
        HashSet hashSet = new HashSet();
        while (foundAMatch.find()) {
            String s = foundAMatch.group(0);
            hashSet.add(s);
        }
```

Comment: I dont understand your question. However `"Input![A-Za-z]+\\d+|Calc![A-Za-z]+\\d+"` Will this solve your problem?

Comment: I'm not understanding this either.  Can you take another pass at it?  I think there's an easy question in here, but your phrasing is convoluted.

Comment: Yes Maybe. But this problem is solved. Sorry for posting here guys.

Comment: My mistake. It was an easy problem and I was almost there.

Answer (score 1):

```
Pattern findMyPattern = Pattern.compile("(?:Input|Calc)![A-Z]\\d+");
```